# SVGs are only correctly rendered when associated with an "application/json" mimeType in web.config -- otherwise there are 406 errors

Tags: .net, angular, iis, svg

I'm having an issue with my Angular/.net application not rendering SVG images when I set the following in web.config:

`<remove fileExtension=".svg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />`

However, SVGs do appear when I set the mimeType incorrectly to application/json:

`<remove fileExtension=".svg" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="application/json" />`

When using the correct one, I'm getting a 406 error for each SVG I'm trying to display. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using the [ng-inline-svg](https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg) directive to pull in the icons from a path, here's the template code:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-6 icon-selection-option" *ngFor="let n of items" (click)="selectFrequencyOption(n)">

  <div *ngIf="n === 'Weekly'" class="icon-selection-column text-center">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'icon-selected': isSelected('Weekly') }" [inlineSVG]="'/assets/images/payroll-frequency/icon-weekly.svg'"></div>
    <span>{{ n }}</span>
    <p>7 day pay period</p>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="n === 'Bi-Weekly'" class="icon-selection-column text-center">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'icon-selected': isSelected('Bi-Weekly') }" [inlineSVG]="'/assets/images/payroll-frequency/icon-biweekly.svg'"></div>
    <span>{{ n }}</span>
    <p>14 day pay period</p>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="n === 'Semi-Monthly'" class="icon-selection-column text-center">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'icon-selected': isSelected('Semi-Monthly') }" [inlineSVG]="'/assets/images/payroll-frequency/icon-semimonthly.svg'"></div>
    <span>{{ n }}</span>
    <p>Two 14-16 day pay periods</p>
  </div>

  <div *ngIf="n === 'Monthly'" class="icon-selection-column text-center">
    <div [ngClass]="{ 'icon-selected': isSelected('Monthly') }" [inlineSVG]="'/assets/images/payroll-frequency/icon-monthly.svg'"></div>
    <span>{{ n }}</span>
    <p>30 day pay period</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: As far as I know, the 406 occurs because the MIME type that is specified in the Accept header of the client request does not match the MIME type that is specified for the requested content file name extension on the server.  To resolve this problem, make sure that the Accept header of the client request matches the MIME type that is specified for the requested content file name extension on the server. Details, you could refer to this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/942050/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-a-server-tha

Comment: Besides,In my opinon, the first config is right. Could you please share the codes about how you render the SVG in your application?

Comment: @BrandoZhang Thanks for the responses. I've added the template code showing how I'm pulling in the SVGs using ng-inline-svg. When I look at the request in Chrome Dev Tools Network inspector, I'm seeing it returned as XHR -- not sure if that helps, this is far from my area of expertise.